# Is there any difference in meaning between the expression "go on a drinking binge," "go on a drinking spree" and "go on a bender"?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning between the expression *go on a drinking binge*, *go on a drinking* *spree* and *go on a bender*? For example:

> Around Christmas many young people **go on a drinking binge**.
>
> Around Christmas many young people **go on a drinking spree**.
>
> Around Christmas many young people **go on a bender**.

Answer (score 1):

A "drinking spree" would be understood, but it isn't really an idiomatic saying. A "spree" is a period of unrestrained activity of any kind.

A "binge" and a "bender" are two different things:

- A **drinking binge** is a *large* amount of alcohol consumed in a *confined* period of time. For example, alcohol licensing laws (which limit the times of day alcohol can be sold) are sometimes said to encourage binge drinking because people try to drink more before the time is called.
- A **bender** is an *extended period* of drinking, usually over more than a day (eg "*I've been on a 3-day bender*")